# python: how to define types for conversion to xml

Tags: python, xml, django, orm, sqlalchemy

I am **implementing a parser in python 2.7 for an xml-based file format**.  The format defines classes with fields of specific types.

**What I want to do** is define objects like this:

```
class DataType1(SomeCoolParent):
    a = Integer()
    b = Float()
    c = String()
    #and so on...
```

- The resulting classes need to be able to be constructed from an XML document, and render back into XML (so that I can save and load files).
- This looks a whole lot like the ORM libraries in SQLAlchemy or Django... except that there is no database, just XML.  It's not clear to me how I would implement what I'm after with those libraries. I would basically want to rip out their backend database stuff and have my own conversion to XML and back again.
- My current plan: set up a metaclass and a parent class (`SomeCoolParent`), define all the types (`Integer`, `Float`, `String`), and generally build a custom almost-ORM myself.  I know how to do this, but it seems that someone else must have done/thought of this before, and maybe come up with a general-purpose solution...
- Is there a "better" way to implement a hierarchy of fixed type structures with python objects, which allows or at least facilitates conversion to XML?

Caveats/Notes

- As mentioned, I'm aware of SQLAlchemy and Django, but I'm not clear on how/whether I can do what I want with their ORM libraries.  Answers that show how to do this with either of them definately count.
- I'm definitely open to other methods, those two are just the ORM libraries I am aware of.

Comment: I'm curious whether approaching this as an XSD Schema (or maybe DTD) would be useful. Searching `xml dtd xsd python orm` yielded some hits such as [generateDS](http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html). Not sure if this gets you where you are going, but since XML has a way to define data types, its worth exploring.

Comment: I also don't know if this will get me where I am going, but it looks like a fantastic option that has a good chance of doing so.  If you want to make that into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a several [XML Schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_schema) specifications out there. My knowledge is somewhat dated but [XML Schema (W3C) - a.k.a. XSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Schema_%28W3C%29) and [relax ng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RELAX_NG) are the most popular with relax ng having a lower learning curve. With that in mind, a good ORM (or would that be OXM 'Object-XML Mapper) using these data description formats ought to be out there. Some candidates are

- [pyxb](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/)
- [generateDS](http://www.davekuhlman.org/generateDS.html)

Stronger google foo may yield more options.